# multithreaded Asynchoronous s3 calls increasing the memory python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I have  1000s of files which needs to be uploaded to s3 and they  are running in a for loop with multithreading threadpool executor with futures which submits to an executor task to put it in s3 and awaits for it finish in the end.

while there is another thread which does some other data processing before it comes out of that process.

During this time my memory consumption is increasing as the files in loops are causing the memory pressure. I am reading the files into memory as bytes to create a hash for deduplication.

Is there any way to reduce the consumption of memory like.

Comment: What is the memory consumption. How many workers are there in the executor? How big is a typical file you upload?

Comment: on an average file size is 176kb i am running 50 process each with 2 threads. 1 thread is doing the puts to s3 and other doing the data processing. Thanks for the response

Comment: `50 process each with 2 threads` can I see some code? 50 processes is too much imo, unless you have 50 threads in your cpu :P

Comment: is the cpu utilization also high all the time?

Comment: CPU isn't high and we have high end systems, which has the capacity hence chose the multiprocessing with threading. Seems to be we have to chunk the data to reduce the memory foot print. If it still consumes more then i might need to go for lesser files at a time and manage them.

Comment: If cpu usage is not high it means that the bottleneck is waiting for the filesystem. threading or asyncio would be better for that, because there's no IPC overhead and no extra memory usage for spawning processes. The ideal solution would be to use consumer producer pattern. ThreadPool that reads the files and puts them in some size-limited queue. ProcessPool for hashing files. But again, i would have to see some code :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am reading the files into memory as bytes to create a hash...

[Use a buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update) and read in chunks:

```
import hashlib

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

with open(filename,'rb') as f: 
    while chunk := f.read(128*sha1.block_size): 
        sha1.update(chunk)

    print(sha1.digest())
```

Answer (score 0):

If the high memory consumption is a caused by reading the files and calculating hash consider doing it more iterative way. It might slow down the whole process but the memory consumption will be much lower:

```
def chunk_file(f, size):
    while data := f.read(size):
        yield data

hasher = hashlib.sha256()
with open("dupa.py", "rb") as f:
    for chunk in chunk_file(f, 1024):
        hasher.update(chunk)
print(hasher.hexdigest())
```

Comment: so this is going to slowdown the memory consumption as the chunk_file will take sometime but lot better than synchronous calls. so this seems to be the only option in reducing the memory consumption with async calls.

Comment: it might not work because mine is image data. Hope this works image data also

Comment: It's not a problem. Also consider using less processes. 50 is a lot